# How can I remove a quote item from an observer from adminpanel in Magento 1?

Tags: magento-1, event-observer, quote, reorder

I want to remove some items if I am pressing the reorder button from adminpanel.
I'm using this event: `controller_action_postdispatch_adminhtml_sales_order_create_reorder`

and this is my method from my observer:

```
    $quote = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session_quote')->getQuote();
    foreach($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {
        if ($item->getSku() === 'with smth') {
            $quote->removeItem($item->getId());
        }
    }
    $quote->collectTotals()->save();
```

I don't get any errors, and the item is not removed :) What am I doing wrong here ? :)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix it by using the `delete()` method:

```
    $quote = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session_quote')->getQuote();
    foreach($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {
        if (my condition here) {
            $item->delete();
        }
    }
```